# How to use multiple filters for cropping videos and setting sound?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to crop video and set sound at the same time. How can I do this?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=2*iw:-1, crop=iw/2:ih/2" -map 0 -c:v -af aecho=0.9:0.3:1000:0.5 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

Do all of your filtering in one [filtergraph](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax-1). A series of filters is called a filterchain. Each filter in a filterchain is separated by a comma. A series of filterchains is the filtergraph. Each filterchain is separated by a semicolon.

Inputs and outputs for each filterchain should be labeled and mapped with the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) as shown below.

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=2*iw:-2, crop=iw/2:ih/2[v]; \
 [0:a]aecho=0.9:0.3:1000:0.5[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

Comment: I've tried this
-filter_complex "[0:v]aecho=0.6:0.3:28:1[v]; [0:a]"volume=1.5"[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"
but except error "stream specifier"

Comment: @CeBiDeX Please show your full command and the complete console output. Use a pastebin site and provide the link.